# How to input multiple files from a directory

Tags: python, xml, unix

First and foremost, I am recently new to Unix and I have tried to find a solution to my question online, but I could not find a solution.

So I am running `Python` through my Unix terminal, and I have a program that parses `xml` files and inputs the results into a `.dat` file.

My program works, but I have to input every single `xml` file (which number over `50`) individually.

For example:

```
clamshell: python3 my_parser2.py 'items-0.xml' 'items-1.xml' 'items-2.xml' 'items-3.xml' .....`
```

So I was wondering if it is possible to read from the directory, which contains all of my files into my program? Rather than typing all the `xml` file names individually and running the program that way.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell itself can expand wildcards so, if you don't care about the order of the input files, just use:

```
python3 my_parser2.py items-*.xml
```

If the numeric order *is* important (you want `0..9`, `10-99` and so on in that order, you may have to adjust the wildcard arguments slightly to guarantee this, such as with:

```
python3 my_parser2.py items-[0-9].xml items-[1-9][0-9].xml items-[1-9][0-9][0-9].xml
```

Comment: Wonderful answer! Thank you for the well written and clear answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
import glob

listOffiles = glob.glob('directory/*.xml')
```

Answer (score 1):

`python3 my_parser2.py *.xml` should work.

Comment: This works fantastic, thank you for the edit and answer!

Answer (score 1):

Other than the command line option, you could just use [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) from within your script and bypass the need for command arguments:

```
import glob 
filenames = glob.glob("*.xml")
```

This will return all `.xml` files (as filenames) in the directory from which you are running the script.

Then, if needed you can simply iterate through all the files with a basic loop:

```
for file in filenames:
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        # do stuff to f.
```

Comment: You're welcome, Yozuru. Don't forget to [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) one of the answers so users with a similar problem will know what worked. :-)